# What is this aircraft with wings seemingly fixed the wrong way?

Tags: aircraft-identification

In [this page](https://surjeetyadav.wordpress.com/author/surjeetyadav/page/2/) there is this image:

[image]

Is it a concept model or a real model?
If this is the latter, then are there real aircraft with such wings?

Comment: What do you mean by wings fixed the wrong way?

Comment: @aeroalias they appear to be installed backwards. Usually the leading edge of the wing makes an angle with the fuselage (sweep angle), and the trailing edge is more perpendicular.

Comment: @aeroalias: Compared to the [Mustang](http://marshallas.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/cessna-citation-mustang.jpg). Here the leading edge seems to be at right angle with the fuselage, but after googling around this seems not so rare.

Comment: Note that plenty of aircraft even have forward-swept leading edges. For example [Ka-13 glider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schleicher_ASK_13) had this to allow flexibility in balance.

Comment: Most of the stuff made by [Mooney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mooney_International_Corporation) has a similar wing profile

Comment: It's now a collector's item, like this [U.S. stamp](https://www.google.com/search?q=upside+down+airplane+stamp&client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&imgil=5WmfWwag5QqYmM%253A%253B8JrPZYihcfTHqM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fen.wikipedia.org%25252Fwiki%25252FInverted_Jenny&source=iu&pf=m&fir=5WmfWwag5QqYmM%253A%252C8JrPZYihcfTHqM%252C_&usg=__YWl4qqIhKMniGgVtjmYMoatBbhY%3D&biw=1089&bih=821&ved=0ahUKEwjNtaXe4M3OAhXGbSYKHTuxAPgQyjcIOQ&ei=giC3V83sBsbbmQG74oLADw#imgrc=5WmfWwag5QqYmM%3A) with an upside down Jenny.

Comment: @mins, by wrong,way, do you mean [forward sweep wing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward-swept_wing)?

Comment: @ManuH: Wrong = The leading edge seems to be at right angle with the fuselage.

Comment: @Andy : indeed. And although leading edges with a smaller angle than trailing edges are extremely rare in larger aircraft, they are very common in case of light general aviation aircraft and gliders.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the [Cessna Citation II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_Citation_II) of which hundreds were built.

[image: Cessna Citation II]

By [Adrian Pingstone](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Arpingstone) - Own work, Public Domain, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=2971403

The wing profile is trapezoidal, as can be seen in the image below.

[image: cessna top view]

Image from [avistar.org](http://www.aviastar.org/pictures/usa/cessna_citation2.gif)

This kind of wing design is found in a number of aircraft, for example the other Cessna Citation series aircraft and the [Embraer Phenom 100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embraer_Phenom_100).

[image: Phenom 100]

By Josh Beasley from USA - Private - Embraer Phenom 100 - N629AS (26/365)Uploaded by [tm](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Tm), CC BY 2.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=25761759

Comment: How deceptive is the image I posted regarding the angles! (and Wikipedia's even more!) Thanks for providing this very useful answer.